# Fullcalendar - change event color based on value

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using latest fullcalendar and was wondering if someone could show me how I could change background color of the event based on its value? For example, if value is Yes then bg is green and if value is No, then bg is red (my Description field is the actual field that contains Yes or No values). Here's the code I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },

   events: "events.php",

   // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>Successful?: <span class='myClass'><b>" + event.description + "</b></span>");
   },
   selectable: false,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: false,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'update_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
   eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: 'update_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 });
```

Thank you.

Comment: While every event object you can add color parameter based on condition like  title: this['EventName'],                              start: this['date'],end: this['date'], id: this['date'], color:'green'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example, you could use eventRender http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/. This sets the elements background color to black if the description is equal to "yes".

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            ...
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                if(event.description == "yes") {
                    element.css('background-color', '#000');
                }
            }, ...
```

Comment: @MarCrazyness what would you do to check for an empty description (e.g.)? I tried it with `if(event.description == ""){};` but that lead me to receiving "undefined"

Comment: Can you send me a fiddle @Flouks ? Your event.description could be null also?