# Specifying the color of an event in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a calendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 300,
    //.............

    events: jsonData,
    month: firstMonth
  })
```

I want to set the `color` of an event dynamically depending of some condition of each value (item) in `jsonData`. How can I do this?

Note that I can't do this:

```
eventSources: [
    {
      events: [  
        {
          title     : 'event1',
          start     : '2012-06-10'
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      textColor: 'yellow'
    },
```

or something because I'd have to break `jsonData` into a 2 parts before passing to calendar and then pass each of them to calendar. I don't want this. Instead I'd like to have some callback function where I can get access to each item and set the color for an event. Something like `eventMouseover`.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683879/fullcalendar-change-event-color-based-on-value/21684352#21684352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggered while an event is being rendered, http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Answer (score 0):

You can write event as a function where you have callback function and you can also use eventsource where you can pass 2 or more jsondata.

Here is the link for it http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/