# change the background color of the events in FullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, python, json, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar v1.6.1 version .
 I want to change the event  background  color in accordance with some conditions,and the rest of events in another color . but I don't know how make to diferent events.

in my table , table name is booking :

```
id --- + ---   the_date   
 1           2014-02-25 
 2           2014-02-26
 3           2014-02-27
 4           2014-03-22
 5           2014-04-15
 6           2014-04-17
```

I want to change the event  background  color of the above dates in red , and rest of the them in green .

Any idea how can i colorize differently each event?

Thanks in advance

Comment: update the Stylesheet according your color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar - change event color based on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683879/fullcalendar-change-event-color-based-on-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `backgroundColor` property for your specific events :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    {
      title: '1',
      start: new Date(2014, 02, 25, 10, 30),
      allDay: false,
      editable: false,
      backgroundColor: '#ED1317'
    },
    {
      title: '2',
      start: new Date(2014, 02, 26, 10, 30),
      allDay: false,
      editable: false,
      backgroundColor: '#ED1317'
    },
    ...
});
```

For the rest of the dates, just use the `.fc-future` and `.fc-today` CSS properties :

```
.fc-future,
.fc-today {
    background-color: #10CC55;
}
```

Comment: but i need to change the background color of the events from today .its display all the days background color in green.i dont need to chnage the background color of the previous days .

Comment: Ok, use the `.fc-future` and `.fc-today` properties.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change background color of events you can use

```
 eventRender: function (event, element, view) 
      {
              var date = new Date(); //this is your todays date

                if (event.start >= date)
                  $(element).css("backgroundColor", "red");

     }
```

and if you want to change background color of day then you can user dayRender CallBack of Fullcalender

```
 dayRender: function (date, element, view) 
        {


                var date = new Date(date);
                var day = date.getDate().toString();
                if (day.length == 1)
                    day = 0 + day;
                var year = date.getFullYear();
                var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                if (month.length == 1)
                    month = 0 + month;
                var dateStr = year + "-" + month + "-" + day ;

                // YourDates is Json array of your default dates

                for (var i = 0; i < YourDates.length; i++) 
               {
                 //here you campare calender dates to your default dates
                   if ( dateStr.toString() == YourDates[i].toString() ) 
                    {
                        $(element).css("background", "red"); // it will set backgroud of that date

                    }

                }


      }
```

**for More Info** :[dayRender:FullCalender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/dayRender/)

Answer (score 1):

The calendar triggers the event **'eventAfterRender'** after each event draw. The same provides access to **event** and **element** as well. You can implement your requirement, by comparing the **event.start** or **event.end** date to current date, and change the color of the **element** as required.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the background color I did in this manner

```
{
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
    backgroundColor: App.getLayoutColorCode('green')
}
```

Hope this helps....