# Why does setting backgroundColor on a fullcalendar event just change the dot color instead of setting the background color?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

### UPDATE

The items appear with the dot and not the background color because they're built with a time of day on them. Remove the time so that `start` is just the date (ie. `2021-12-07`), then they get the background color correctly as expected so the question now becomes how to get the background color even with the time of day on them...

---

Referencing

- [change the background color of the events in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038755/change-the-background-color-of-the-events-in-fullcalendar), and
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventBackgroundColor

I've added `backgroundColor` values to my events, but this only seems to change the dot on the events:

[image]

You'll notice that using `extendedProps` to set the background color doesn't work either.

I'm trying to get the event to appear in a block of the given color similar to this:
[image]

Here's my events array; how can I get fullcalendar to change the background color on the event?

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'event1',
        start: '2021-12-07T08:00:00',
        backgroundColor: '#ff00ff'
    },
    {
        title: 'event3',
        start: '2021-12-07T09:00:00',
        backgroundColor: '#4d96f1'
    },
    {
        title: 'event2',
        start: '2021-12-08T08:00:00',
        backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
        extendedProps: {
            backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
        },
    }
],
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also keep the timed events aspect but showing them as the same way as in all day by just adding `eventDisplay:'block',` in your Fullcalendar's parameters.

Comment: Oh I didn't spot that! I'll let you know in about 12-15 hours how it goes. Could help with 1 particular view I'm working with.